# How to overcome "same JVM signature" error when implementing a Java interface?

Tags: kotlin

With the code below, I am getting the following error in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6 and Kotlin plugin 0.11.91.AndroidStudio.3:

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getName()Ljava/lang/String;):
  • public open fun getName(): kotlin.String?
  • internal final fun <get-name>(): kotlin.String?
```

Java class, `JavaInterface.java`:

```
public interface JavaInterface {
  public String getName();
}
```

Kotlin class, `KotlinClass.kt`

```
public class KotlinClass(val name: String?) : JavaInterface
```

I've tried overriding the 'getter' method by
adding `override fun getName(): String? = name`, but that produces the same error.

I can see one workaround by doing this instead:

```
public class KotlinClass(val namePrivate: String?) : JavaInterface {
  override fun getName(): String? = namePrivate
}
```

But in my real-world case I have a number of properties to implement and need setters too. Doing this for each property doesn't seem very Kotlin-ish. What am I missing?

Comment: You can not override Java methods with Kotlin properties at the moment. It would be nice if we could support it, but we don't know how to do it consistently for mixed hierarchies

Comment: what about adding a more desccriptive error message? saying that you can't override java methods with properties...it would be less cofusing

Comment: I guess the best is to rewrite the interface in Kotlin...

Comment: Any update on overriding getter/setter methods with Kotlin properties? All these answers feel like workarounds to avoid the name clash issue, and most of the time you just want to return the property anyway. 

@lrn2code This will not work either. If you have a Kotlin class `class KotlinClass(var name: String) : SomeInterface` and a Kotlin interface `interface SomeInterface { fun getName(): String }`, this will produce the same error during compilation as using the original Java interface.

Comment: Ah, I see now. A better solution is to use properties directly in interfaces when rewriting them in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces Still doesn't help when you need to work with Java.

Comment: look in your code somewhere you have the same function just give a different name to it bcz kotlin give you setter getter as internal implementation so if you literally want setter or getter there is another way to do that like set and get key below the variable and given your implementation. its a name conflict

Comment: convert function to property instead of initializing property from a function.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Making that variable `private` solves the problem.

`public class KotlinClass(private val name: String?) : JavaInterface`

Comment: I don't know if that was possible in Kotlin 0.11, but it works in 1.1 and feels better than having different variable names.

Comment: If variable needs to be public?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Kotlin 1.2:
> Class 'KotlinClass' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun getName(): String! defined in JavaInterface

Answer (score 23):

You could use  @JvmField for instructs the compiler not generate getter/setter, and you can implement your setters and getters. With this your code work well in Java (as attribute getter/setter) and Kotlin as property

Example:
**JAVA**:

```
public interface Identifiable<ID extends Serializable> 
{
   ID getId();
}
```

**KOTLIN**:

```
class IdentifiableImpl(@JvmField var id: String) :Identifiable<String> 
{
   override fun getId(): String 
   {
       TODO("not implemented")
   }
}
```

Comment: This strikes me as the best answer.  It directly addresses the issue and works for other cases where the accepted answer won't.

Comment: Exactly, as @RobertLiberatore said this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

The annotation feature of Kotlin named `@JvmName` will solve the duplication problem in Java and Kotlin when having the same signature.

```
fun function(p: String) {
   // ...
}

// Signature: function(Ljava/lang/String)
```

With the use of `JvmName` will be:

```
@JvmName("functionOfKotlin")
fun function(p: String) {
   // ...
}

// Signature: functionOfKotlin(Ljava/lang/String)
```

This just [doesn't work for interfaces yet](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31420/Support-JvmName-on-interface-or-provide-other-interface-evolution-mechanism) as of May 2023

Answer (score 5):

IMHO most readable combination is field + explicit interface implementation by the single-expression function (combination of @Renato Garcia's and @Steven Spungin's answers):

Java:

```
public inteface SomeInterface {
    String getFoo();
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class Implementation(@JvmField val foo: String) : SomeInterface {
    override fun getFoo() = foo
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another work-around is to declare the properties in an abstract Kotlin class, then write a small java class that extends KotlinClass and implements JavaInterface.

```
// JavaInterface.java
public interface JavaInterface {
    int getFoo();
    void setFoo(int value);
}

// KotlinClass.kt
abstract class KotlinClass(open var foo : Int = 0) {
}

// JavaAdapter.java
class JavaAdapter extends KotlinClass implements JavaInterface {
    // all code in KotlinClass, but can't implement JavaInterface there
    // because kotlin properties cannot override java methods.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We have found that to use the same names without clashing, the ctor args must be **private** *AND* you must **still override** the interfaces methods. You don't need any *additional* backing fields. Also, your expression body assignment will not recurse, so you can safely use that syntax.

Java Interface

```
interface IUser {
    String getUserScope();
    String getUserId();
}
```

Kotlin Class

```
class SampleUser(private val userScope: String, private val userId: String) : IUser {
    override fun getUserId() = userId
    override fun getUserScope() = userScope
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have direct control over the interface then the best approach is to write the interface in Kotlin. You can then write your class

```
public class KotlinClass(override val name: String?) : KotlinInterface
```

and still reference it from any Java code using the same interface as before. This looks a lot neater than setting all the properties to private and overriding the get function. Obviously if you can't migrate the interface to Java because you don't own it then that seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface JavaInterface {
    public String getName();
}

public class KotlinClass(val namePrivate: String?) : JavaInterface {

private var name = namePrivate

    override fun getName(): String? {
        return name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the variable to something else, or make it private if u dont want it to be public.

Answer (score 0):

convert function to property instead of initializing property from a function.
for ex:

```
    fun getCountriesList(): List<Country> {
    val countries = mutableListOf<Country>()
    countries.add(Country("in", "+91", "India", R.drawable.indian_flag))
    countries.add(Country("us", "+1", "United States",R.drawable.us_flag))
    return countries
}
```

to

```
 val countriesList: List<Country>
    get() {
        val countries = mutableListOf<Country>()
        countries.add(Country("in", "+91", "India", R.drawable.indian_flag))
        countries.add(Country("us", "+1", "United States", R.drawable.us_flag))
        return countries
    }
```