# Interface's function clashes with Property's getter

Tags: kotlin

An interface's function name clashes with a property's getter name intentionally, but it's prohibited by the compiler because of accidental override problem. Is it possible to instruct the compiler this is intentional?

```
interface A {
  fun getFoo()
}

class B: A {
  val foo
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This feature seems not to be implemented in any way.

@AndreyBreslav's comment on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268526/how-to-overcome-same-jvm-signature-error-when-implementing-a-java-interface):

> You can not override Java methods with Kotlin properties at the moment. It would be nice if we could support it, but we don't know how to do it consistently for mixed hierarchies

---

This does not solve your problem but at least makes the code compile: you can change JVM name of the getter with the [`@JvmName` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-name/):

```
interface A {
    fun getFoo(): SomeType
}

class B: A {
    override fun getFoo() = foo

    val foo: SomeType = someValue()
        @JvmName("getFoo_") get() = field
}
```

---

Also, consider changing to a more idiomatic approach: define the `val`-property in your interface, so that you can override it in the implementations:

```
interface A {
    val foo: SomeType
}

class B : A {
    override val foo: SomeType = someValue()
}

class C : A {
    override val foo: SomeType
        get() = someCustomGetter()
}
```

Comment: UPD: Added a more Kotlin-idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 5):

The Kotlin-idiomatic approach from the answer above is OK until we stick with Kotlin, but if these interface are defined in Java it's not applicable. There're a plenty of propositions reported in [KT-6653](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653) but none of them is currently implemented. I'm currently writing some app which is partially in Java and partially in Kotlin and this problem completely kills "Kotlin-Java interoperability" concept.

The only solution I've found to workaround it is the following one:

```java
public interface A {
  String getFoo();
}
```

```kotlin
class B(private val _foo: String): A {

  override fun getFoo(): String = _foo

}
```

It's also possible to extend this class with setter:

```kotlin
class B(private var _foo: String): A {

  override fun getFoo(): String = _foo

  fun setFoo(foo: String) {
    _foo = foo
  }

}
```