# "Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature" when implementing Java interface

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I faced the following error trying to extend RuntimeException and implement [GraphQLError](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/GraphQLError.java) interface, defined in Java, from my Kotlin code. This is the error:

> Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getMessage()Ljava.lang.string;):
>
> `public open fun <get-message>(): String? defined in NegativeCountException`
> `public open fun getMessage(): String? defined in NegativeCountException`

The following is my code:

```
class NegativeCountException() : RuntimeException(), GraphQLError {
  override fun getMessage(): String? {
    TODO("not implemented")
  }
  <...>
}
```

where `GraphQLError` is an interface, defined in Java as shown bellow:

```
public interface GraphQLError {
  String getMessage();
  <...>
}
```

Seems like it clashes with `getMessage()` defined in `Throwable`.

I can't change code of the interface, because it comes from a library.

**How can I create my own runtime exception, that will implement [GraphQLError](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/GraphQLError.java)?**

---

PS: I also tried the following, and received a very similar error:

```
class NegativeCountException(override val message: String?) : RuntimeException(), GraphQLError {
  <...>
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `val message` hidden inside `<...>`? That's what the error seems to say.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, I'm sure - there is no message property defined by me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035263/accidental-override-the-following-declarations-have-the-same-jvm-signature)

Comment: This has a solution that worked for me: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/1022

Answer (score 2):

This is a graphql problem. My workaround:

Reimplement GraphQLError, ExceptionWhileDataFetching and DataFetcherErrorHandler.

KGraphQLError is a "fixed" kotlin interface (with val instead of getters) that you use for your custom errors.

in KDataFetcherErrorHandler: Replace `ExceptionWhileDataFetching` in this line with `KExceptionWhileDataFetching`:
`val error = ExceptionWhileDataFetching(path, exception, sourceLocation)`

`KExceptionWhileErrorHandling` implements `GraphQLError`. Look through the code and replace all instances of `if (exception is GraphQLError)` with `(exception is KGraphQLError)`

Pass the new `KDataFetcherErrorHandler` to your queryExecutionStrategy and mutationExecutionStrategy.

Your custom errors can now extend Throwable and implement KGraphQLError, and get handled properly.

More info here: http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execution.html

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a GraphQL problem. It's definitely a Kotlin problem, namely, that it doesn't allow to easily resolve this ambiguity. 2.5 years later, in Kotlin 1.4, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work, when message was not a field in the one class (Throwable) and a method in the other. But it seems kotlin can not resolve the ambiguity when message is a field in the class and a method in the interface. If you have control over your GraphQlError you could do this:

```
class NegativeCountException() : RuntimeException(), GraphQLError {
    override val message: String?
        get() = super.message
}

interface GraphQLError {
    val message: String?
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have no control over the interface.

Comment: This is the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653

Answer (score 0):

This is because Kotlin will create getters and setters for your variables when generating Java byte code. For example,

```
class Foo(val bar)
```

`Foo` with have `getBar` in Java byte code. To avoid name conflict, use `@JvmField` and `@JvmName`.

Read more about this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html).

Comment: The problem is that I define no properties. Moreover, I do define nothing. The only thing I do is overriding of getMessage method, which is defined in both: abstract class Throwable and interface GraphQLError.

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky Your `NegativeCountException` constructor has `override val message: String?`. `var` and `val` in constructor is class variables.

Comment: It was an additional try. Take a look, please, at the main example, where I have no properties defined.

Comment: I added a link to sources of GraphQLError. Probably it may help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, in my understanding, since getMessage is implemented in Throwable, it should be considered as implementation for getMessage defined in GraphQLError (signatures are the same), so that I need to override nothing. But it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky I understand your problem now. But do you have control on `GraphQLError`? As far as I know, there isn't a way to work around this. It also happens when there are name conflicts in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and dirty workaround, in case your project allows Java alongside Kolin.
Write your `NegativeCountException` in Java :D

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a good solution for this (provided [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/1022)):

```
class NegativeCountException(@JvmField override val message: String) : RuntimeException(message), GraphQLError {
    override fun getMessage(): String? = super.message
  <...>
}
```