# Why having setText() on text field Kotlin compiler compains?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private class FakeCardDrawable constructor(
    context: Context) : CardDrawable(context) {
    var text: String? = null
    var backgroundColor = 0
    var textColor = 0


    override fun setColors(
        backgroundColor: Int, textColor: Int, animate: Boolean
    ) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        this.textColor = textColor
    }

     fun setText(text: String) {
        this.text = text
    }
}
```

It complains saying "Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature(setText..)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035263/accidental-override-the-following-declarations-have-the-same-jvm-signature

Comment: `setText()` method is auto-generated by kotlin compilers, you don't need the overhead to implement them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `var text` and your function `setText()` are both translated into JVM to a public method named `setText()`.

To avoid platform declaration clash you have 3 options here:

1. Change the name of `var text` or the name of `setText`
2. Make `var text` with a private `set`:

```kotlin
var text: String? = null
  private set
```

3. Change the JVM name of the method:

```kotlin
@JvmName("myJvmName")
fun setText(text: String) {
    this.text = text
}
```